# Comparing two text files using PHP

Tags: java, php

I have a textfile created dynamically by running following lines of code.

```
 if (system('javac main.java 2>ErrorFile.txt')!==false)
    {
        exec('java main 1>OutputFile.txt<filename.txt');
    }
```

I now want to compare the OutputFile.txt with sample.txt. And i used the below function but it didn't help me. Can anyone help me out please!

```
function filecomparision($a, $b) {
   if(filesize($a) !== filesize($b)){
        return false;   $ah = fopen($a, 'rb');   $bh = fopen($b, 'rb');
        $result = true;   while(!feof($ah)) {
             if(fread($ah, 8192) != fread($bh, 8192)) {
               $result = false;
               break;
             }   
        }
        fclose($ah);   fclose($bh);
        return $result; 
   }
}
```

When i tried the above function i got two differnt sizes for my files even though the content is same. And it's showing contents of OutputFile.txt as octal-content.

Comment: you should use the tag php instead.

Comment: Why are you using the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: I am running  java code using php and saving it's output in OutputFile.txt  @YassinHajaj

Comment: do you need to check content identity or show the differences? If you don't show the differences, you can use a hash.. like `if (md5(file_get_contents($a)) == md5(file_get_contents($b))) {/*files has the same content*/}`

Comment: First at all, did you check manually if both files really have same content? Take care about ending break lines, open the files with a plain text editor and show all chars.

Once you are sure about that, you can focus on your comparison function.

Comment: They both have different type of EOL .Is there any other way to compare both the files?

Comment: Here is not enough info how to compare it. Did spaces before/after string, two or more spaces between words affects on comparing? What encoding you use (utf-8, utf-16, unicode, etc)? ... maybe it easier to check what EOL used by OS and generate correct output?

Comment: I even want to compare white spaces. And i am using windows10 . And all the solutions in this page worked when i used them to compare outputs of C, C++ Codes. I am facing problem only with java. @Wizard

Comment: And i am running java code using jre8

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $a string
 * @param $b string
 * @return bool
 */
function filecomparision($a, $b) {
    // assuming both of files are exists
    return md5(file_get_contents($a)) === md5(file_get_contents($b));
}
```

> Suggestion: You can have different sizes while contents seems are identical, coz your java-application can use another character set or different EOL-marker.

I've no idea how to make it correct. You can try to replace EOL.

```
<?php
function filecomparision($a, $b) {
    // assuming both of files are exists
    $a = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|\r)/', "\n", file_get_contents($a));
    $b = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|\r)/', "\n", file_get_contents($b));
    return md5($a) === md5($b);
}
```

> update for this particular case:

```
<?php
function filecomparision($a, $b) {
    // assuming both of files are exists
    $a = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|\r)/', "\n", rtrim(file_get_contents($a)));
    $b = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n\r|\r)/', "\n", rtrim(file_get_contents($b)));
    return md5($a) === md5($b);
}
```

Comment: @MaheshwarReddyk what kind of problem or errors you have ?

Comment: The function is returning false even when the content is same

Comment: It cannot be. Did you try to cal a function when both parameters are the same filename?

Comment: Yes. It's working when i give same file name to both parameters. And i used mime_content_type for both the files to know the type of content in file. One file has text/plain content and another has application /octet-stream

Comment: I guess your java-application generate slightly different output file. May be invisible characters has another codes, or your EOL-marker is '\n' when php used '\r\n' or vice versa, may be you have EOL at the EOF, while another one hasn't. This function returns TRUE when both of files identical down to the byte. You can try to view both files inside any hex-editor, or use `diff`-tool - and, I'm sure, you will see that your files are not identical.

Comment: Yes they are different.  Is there any other way that i can compare both the files?

Comment: No it didn't help me.

Comment: If your files have a different MD5 your files are different and theres no way to pinpoint the difference unless you compare them in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I tried overwriting the file stripping out extra characters.

```
     $v = rtrim(file_get_contents($b),"\x0D\x0A");   
     $MyFile = fopen($b, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
     fwrite($MyFile,$v);
     fclose($MyFile);
```

I appended this code and everything is working fine now.

Comment: It was what I said before... "...may be you have EOL at the EOF, while another one hasn't..."